# Check if value in Column A of Table 1 exists in Column A of Table 2, and if it does, get value from Column B in Table 2 in Excel

Tags: excel, match

In Excel, I have two sheets (Table 1 and Table 2)

I have a list of names in column A of Table 1, and a list of names in column A of Table 2. I want to check Column A of Table 2, to see if it contains a name from Column A of Table 1. If it does, I want to get the row of where the match was found in Table 2, and get a value from Column B in Table 2

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) or [`INDEX`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) / [`MATCH`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a) are what you're looking for

Comment: Fair enough, just tried it though and I'm getting a REF error when trying to lookup the value. I know I have the correct Lookup Value (starting on A2 of Table 1), my table array is $A$2:$A$250, my column index is 31 (Column AE), and I have Range Lookup set to FALSE for an exact match

https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2020/02/12/vlookup-multiple-sheets-excel-examples/

Following this example

NVM I'm a dingus, figured it out. Thanks :D

Comment: Please [edit you question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68443086/edit) to let us know what you are using, exactly. Sample data would also be useful